# Leave arguments untouched with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I would like use argparse to parse the arguments that it knows and then leave the rest untouched. For example I want to be able to run

```
performance -o output other_script.py -a opt1 -b opt2
```

Which uses the `-o` option and leaves the rest untouched.

The module profiler.py does a similar thing with optparse, but since I'm using argparse I'm doing:

```
def parse_arguments():
    parser = new_argument_parser('show the performance of the given run script')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', default='profiled.prof')

    return parser.parse_known_args()

def main():
    progname = sys.argv[1]
    ns, other_args = parse_arguments()
    sys.argv[:] = other_args
```

Which also seems to work, but what happens if also other_script.py also has a `-o` flag?

Is there in general a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`argparse` will stop to parse argument until EOF or `--`. If you want to have argument without beeing parsed by argparse, you can write::

```
python [PYTHONOPTS] yourfile.py [YOURFILEOPT] -- [ANYTHINGELSE]
```

Comment: Ah didn't know about that thanks! Without a marker it would be in fact very hard for argparse to understand what's going on I guess, it's not an easy problem..

Comment: It should be clarified that you need to use the `parse_known_args()` method (at least on python3.6)

Comment: This is not correct (at least not in 2018). `parse_args` will error and show usage after `--` (unless you've added that as an argument with a proper `dest`). `parse_known_args` is closer to working, but there the bare `--` isn't necessary at all.

Answer (score 20):

You could also add a positional argument to your parser with `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`, to capture the script and its options:

```
# In script 'performance'...
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-o")
p.add_argument("command", nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
args = p.parse_args()
print args
```

Running the above minimal script...

```
$ performance -o output other_script.py -a opt1 -b opt2
Namespace(command=['performance', '-a', 'opt1', '-b', 'opt2'], o='output')
```

Comment: also `parse_known_args` should do this.

Comment: This seems to leave even `--` intact. Perfect!